# Android HTTPS streaming with 2.3.3

Tags: android

I was having an issue with a Video File hosted on a Amazon s3 server. I create a pre-signed URL and feed that URL to a video view. On ICS and above the VideoView plays the file, but in android 2.3.3 it fails to play the file. I remove the 's' from the https pre-signed url and now the videoview can play the file ? Whats going on here? Any ideas ?

Kind Regards,